# DragLeave and DragEnter are not working

Tags: wpf, xaml

On a canvas I have placed a  and inside of the Dock an  is located as following:

```
<DockPanel DragEnter="DockPanel_DragEnter" DragLeave="DockPanel_DragLeave">
    <Expander Header="Controls" IsExpanded="False"
              Content="{StaticResource CustomControls }"
              DragLeave="Expander_DragLeave"/>
</DockPanel>
```

The goal is to drag some control or shapes from the dock and drop them on canvas. I have tired `DragLeave` and `DragEnter` events on both Expander and DockPanl but none of them get triggered!

What am I missing here?

Thanks.
Amit

Comment: Have you set the UIElement.AllowDrop property and are you calling DragDrop.DoDragDrop from your code?  Those are required before any Drag events will fire.

Comment: AllowDrop no!!! I just added it and now it gets triggered but why should we set AllowDrop? because we are dragging in this phase no dropping! it was a big help for me Thanks!

Comment: DragEnter indicates that a drag drop operation is active and the mouse is hovering over a control that can receive the drag drop.  The control that receives it gets a "DragEnter" event and it can respond to it using the event args.  A control that has AllowDrop set to false will never get a DragEnter.